# Why is the symbol ζ sometimes used in a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

I just flipped through a book on complex analysis and found some functions being written as f(ζ) instead of f(z). It did not state why this is so. Can someone help enlighten me? Thank you.

Comment: Zeta ($\zeta$) is the Greek letter corresponding to z. As far as I remember, it is often introduced when we are already using z (as in the Cauchy integration formula).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the two variables z and ζ will correspond to different complex values?

Comment: $w$ is also commonly used as a complex variable...

Comment: When studying functions of one *real* variable one uses $x$, $t$, or $r$ (and other letters) as names for the independent variable. In the same way one uses $z$, $\zeta$, or $w$ (and other letters) as names for a *complex* independent variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: When people ask me questions like this in person, I have a tendency to burst into the song "Tradition" from *Fiddler on the Roof*.  It's a little harder to do on the Internet.  But I can still respond: "You may ask, how did this tradition get started?  I'll tell you: ... I don't know."

Answer (score 2):

Zeta ($\zeta$) is the Greek letter corresponding to z. As far as I remember, it is often introduced when we are already using z (as in the Cauchy integration formula). -- [sos440](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850678/why-is-the-symbol-%ce%b6-sometimes-used-in-a-complex-function#comment1754248_850678)

When studying functions of one *real* variable one uses $x$, $t$, or $r$ (and other letters) as names for the independent variable. In the same way one uses $z$, $\zeta$, or $w$ (and other letters) as names for a *complex* independent variable. -- [Christian Blatter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850678/why-is-the-symbol-%ce%b6-sometimes-used-in-a-complex-function#comment1755191_850678)

(Also, some people prefer using $w$ for dependent variable, as in $w=f(z)$; then $\zeta$ becomes the preferred choice for a second instance of independent variable.)